# Filter records from table in R

Tags: r, jupyter-irkernel

I have a dataset Movies.

```
head(Movies)
```

[image: output of head(Movies)]

How to fetch rows where MovieID is "0000008"?
I have tried:

```
t1 = subset(Movies, "MovieID" == "0000008")
t2 <- Movies[ which(Movies["MovieID"]=="0000008"), ]
head(t1)
head(t2)
```

Both return empty datasets, which is wrong as I can see a row with ID "0000008".

Edit:
I have tried removing "" from MovieID, but that throws error:

> Error in subset.matrix(Movies, MovieID == "0000008"): object 'MovieID' not found

Edit:
The Movie data was obtained as:

```
URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sidooms/MovieTweetings/master/latest/movies.dat"
MovieText = readLines( remote.file(URL) ) # HACK!!!
Movies = matrix( sapply( MovieText,
            function(x) unlist(strsplit(sub(" [(]([0-9]+)[)]", "::\\1",x),"::"))[1:4] ),
            nrow=length(MovieText), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE )
colnames(Movies) = c("MovieID", "MovieTitle", "Year", "Genres")
```

Comment: It can be `subset(Movies, MovieID == "0000008")`

Comment: Not putting MovieID in "" throws error:  Error in subset.matrix(Movies, MovieID == "0000008"): object 'MovieID' not found

Comment: Please show the dput of your example data.  It should work in normal data

Comment: library(dplyr);
Movies %>% filter(MovieID == "0000008")

Comment: Yes. I am sure. You can see that from the image I have posted.

Comment: class(Movies$MovieID) is it really a character string?

Comment: Is Movie a dataframe ?

Comment: I got the Movies dataset from URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sidooms/MovieTweetings/master/latest/movies.dat" and then converted it to matrix. I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: @SocialFunction, MovieID is a atomic variable, so I had to use class(Movies["MovieID"]). I got 'character'

Comment: Would you paste the result of `dput(Movies)`? (Edit: Just saw @akrun asking for that earlier, soryy for duplicate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `nrow` should be `length(MovieText)/4`

```
URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sidooms/MovieTweetings/master/latest/movies.dat"
MovieText = readLines( URL ) # HACK!!!
Movies = matrix( sapply( MovieText,
    function(x) unlist(strsplit(sub(" [(]([0-9]+)[)]", "::\\1",x),"::"))[1:4] ),
    nrow=length(MovieText)/4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE )
colnames(Movies) = c("MovieID", "MovieTitle", "Year", "Genres")

#if you want to work with matrix, then use this
subset(Movies, Movies[,"MovieID"]=="0000008")
```

#### Edit: `data.frame` and `data.table` subsetting

```
library(data.table)

MoviesDF <- data.frame(Movies)
MoviesDT <- data.table(Movies)

MoviesDF[MoviesDF["MovieID"] == "0000008", ]
MoviesDT[MovieID == "0000008", ]
```

BTW: Love the **HACK!!!** comment.

Comment: And just by using matrix subsetting: `Movies[Movies[, "MovieID"] == "0000008", ]`. But it would be a good idead to just use `data.frame`...

Comment: @SonuKMishra, see the comment above, use `data.frame` to work with anything more complicated than a matrix of numbers.

Comment: @M.D Thanks! I am quite new to R, so not aware of these stuffs! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SonuKMishra, next steps would be `dplyr` and `data.table` then!

Comment: @M.D feel free to rewrite this solution. SonuKMishra, you should remove the tick and tick his answer tomorrow

Comment: @chinsoon12, no way, your answer works perfect for the question stated.

Comment: @M.D its more important to learn than to fix a particular problem

Comment: @chinsoon12, I have edited your answer, hope it is okay with you.